# Every widget on android UI is a View object?

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, android-preferences, robotium

I read on SDk says that View represents the basic building block for user interface components. I'm wondering is dialog or preference can also be regarded as View object? Can I get all the widget on current activity by Robotium's getCurrentViews() method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

each direct and indirect subclasses are listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) (sections "Known Direct Subclasses" and "Known Indirect Subclasses"

According to this you will get list of all Views such as Buttons, ImageViews, ImageButtons etc